# CSS Unicode not working

Tags: html, css

When i change the unicode of any of the code below, it doesn't work and i don't know why. it seems it only works with just this default ones i copied from the internet.

```
 .demo-wrapper .panel.left a:before {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        top: 15px;
        left: 20px;
        font-family: 'hk-demo';
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .demo-wrapper .panel.left .newsfeed a:before { 
        content: '\f09e';
    }
    .demo-wrapper .panel.left .profile a:before { 
        content: 'ðŸ‘¤';
    }

.demo-wrapper .panel.left .setting a:before { 
    content: '\2699';
}
.demo-wrapper .panel.left .logout a:before { 
    content: '\e78e';
}
.demo-wrapper .panel.left .report a:before { 
    content: '\f0e0';
}
```

for instance when i change \f09e' to \f03e it doesn't work. i've tried multiple unicode codes it doesn't work till i use the default ones i got from the internet

.can someone please solve it for me

Comment: What is "doesn't work"? Characters in the range E000 through F8FF are _private use_ characters, which means they may or may not be displayed at all. So what do you expect to happen? I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Lmkd2/) where if I change the f09e to f03e, it shows a undefined character in both cases.

Comment: when i preview it give me the wrong image, something like a default one

Comment: Are you sure that the browser is using the correct font?

Comment: really sure, because the codes listed above are able to display correct, but when i change it, it doesn't work